# Migration from xerces v1 to xerces v3.1.1

Tags: c++, xerces-c

I have to migrate my project from xerces 1 to xerces 3.1.1 but I can't find DOMString.hpp.  Does someone have an idea where I can find this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMString` is [gone](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/exp/glast/ground/notes/XercesConversion.shtml) in Xerces-C++ 3. Instead, the Xerces API gives you null-terminated `XMLCh` strings.

Comment: thanks for your answer, there is a release method in XMLString (xerces-c 1.7)?

Comment: @nidhal: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: i use xerces 1 in this method

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& target, const DOMString& s)
    
    {
        char *p = s.transcode(); // method from xerces
        target << p;
        return target;
    }

and i need to delete my object p i need to call XMLString::release from xerces but there is no release method in xerces 1, it added in later versions, i need to know in which version of xerces they put XMLString::release.

Comment: @nidhal: it's there: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLString.html