# What is the difference between DOMString and string?

Tags: c++, linux, string, solaris, xerces-c

I'm migrating a (very) old application from solaris to linux.

In c++ code, an old version of xerces library was used. So I updated that library to a more recent one.

My problem is that before the type "DOMString" from the library was used but it doesn't exist anymore in the newest version.

I'd like to know what is the difference between DOMString from xerces and string ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration from xerces v1 to xerces v3.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491125/migration-from-xerces-v1-to-xerces-v3-1-1)